# Html5 video perspective transform

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, perspective

Would it be possible to set via CSS or jquery video perspective to fit exactly where and how I need it ?

See picture:

[image]

I want the video to fit in the red area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I think that it would be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to familiarize yourself with CSS3 `transform` and `perspective` properties.

```css
.video-wrapper {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
video {
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video width="400" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

Without going through all of the effort to create a solution, you can use an HTML5 `canvas` element

Comment: You should keep trying. The best way to learn how to do something is to practice.

Comment: Figured it out after all :P. Thanks

Comment: can you tell us how please? :)